# Integrating a custom tool that generates C# into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a custom tool that generates strongly-typed C# data structures to access external data sources of various kinds. I would like to integrate it into VS so the generated source automatically gets found and compiled and shows up in IntelliSense (as I've seen other tools do, such as T4). This is for an open source project, to be distributed.

Currently the tool uses command line arguments, but it could easily read a configuration files instead, to provide a convenient hook. I can do it as a pre-build step, but that's much less convenient to set up. I could rewrite it as a T4 macro, but that kind of misses the point.

I'm aware of writing a custom tool for a code-behind as per [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31257/Custom-Tools-Explained). That's a lot of work, particularly writing the installer for it to be distributed.

I'm hoping there is a nice way to do this that I just don't know about.

Comment: Are your end-users expected to edit the C# code that the tool has generated, or should it remain read-only?

Comment: Actually, writing an installer that registers a COM component and then adds some registry values for VS is a breeze if you use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/). I would think that a "custom tool" might be the best way to go.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, the output is just templated class definitions that are laborious to write by hand. No point in ever editing them (unless the tool gets it wrong!).

Comment: @karl: I guess I'm more concerned with the user experience. Currently I use only project-based components installed by NuGet during an Msbuild and it's easy to test. An installer followed by a VS restart is a bigger ask for the user, and much harder to test.

Comment: Well any type of integration into VS will be required to be installed one way or the other, not sure how you would get around it. You can run powershell scripts when installing a nuget package though so maybe you could bundle it with your ordinary package (or just show a page telling your users that the extension is available).